# Evaluate() not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to `evaluate`. So if the following code works

```
If Evaluate("=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(" & temp & ",C:C,0)))") Then
```

why doesn't this one below??

```
If Evaluate("=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(" & c & ",sal,0)))") Then
```

temp is a string and c is an element in an array that looks to be stored as a string as well. C:C is range on activesheet. sal is a range on a separate sheet.

```
Set wsSal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sal Sum")    
Set sal = wsSal.Range("C17:C50")
```

I have tried

```
If Evaluate("=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(c ,sal,0)))") Then
```

which gives me a run time error 13 type mismatch.

By not working, the former enters the if statement, the latter does not.

Comment: Because `sal` is a variable you've defined in code (like `c`), and can't just be embedded inside the `"`s in `Evaluate`. You're not using `Match(temp,C:C, 0)))`, but `Match(" & temp & ",C:C, 0)))` - concatenating the string to include *temp* with `&`. Just embedding it in the formula the way you are simply passes a meaningless word (`sal`) that the fomula has no way to resolve. Fix it by not using `sal` at all, and concatenate in the string `C17:C50` instead just like you did `temp`.

Comment: `If Evaluate("=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(" & c & " ," & sal & ",0)))") Then` still failed :/

Comment: Read what I wrote again. I've edited it while you were testing. :-)

Comment: Ok but C17:C50 isn't on activesheet. Be a pain to qualify it all...

Comment: Worksheets also have an `Evaluate` method - if you use `wsSal.Evaluate()` then it will operate in the context of wsSal and not the active sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining `sal` as an object variable and setting it to the range, you can create a defined name called, `sal`.

Open the Name Manager from a worksheet.

Enter the name 'sal`

In the `Refers To` field, enter `='Sal Sum'!$C$17:$C$50`

Confirm the name.

Now you can use Evaluate() with `sal` the way you have described.

**UPDATE**

Here is another way that you may find easier to maintain.

Make `wsSal` a module-level variable.

Make `sal_` a module-level constant:

```
Const sal = "C17:C50"
```

Make a function:

```
Function sal()
    sal = wsSal.Range(sal_)
End Function
```

Now you can use Evaluate() with `sal` the way you have described.

Comment: Ah. Clever. But That range will change by workbook. Don't want to have to set named ranges each time.

Comment: @findwindow I added an update to address your concern.